# Using High Resolution on Game using lower monitor resolution on notebook ASUS

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, resolution, asus-laptop

I'm playing a game and using GeDoSato game profile that can add custom render resolution that is not on this game. For example, the max resolution is 1366 x 768 on that game.

By using GeDoSato, I can render resolution, for example 3200 x 1800 so I can play using that resolution.

The problem is on GeDoSato we can downsampling it or show it with 3200 x 1800 resolution but its over limit the monitor so what I see is half of display.
What I want is how to settings it so if I'm using 3200 x 1800 display on 1366 x 768 monitor, it not showing half display.

But showing 3200 x 1800 on a 1366 x 768 monitor is by shrunken display or make it smaller than normal. So what I mean is 3200 x 1800 resolution is FIT on 1366 x 768 without downsampling.

Because I already had an old monitor, that monitor maximum resolution is 800 x 600 as far as I remember. But my graphic resolution until 1024 x 768. I tried setting the resolution graphic into 1024 x 768. So it means over the maximum resolution monitor.

It's working, but with smaller text, picture.

That is what I want. Using High Resolution than maximum monitor and the display is FIT but smaller.

Can someone help me? How to set it?

I'm using notebook ASUS with specification:

1. OS: Windows 10
2. Display Adapter: Intel(R) HD Graphics 620
3. VGA : Nvidia GeForce 930M
4. Max Resolution on my notebook: 1366 x 768
5. ASUS
6. Type : A456URK -> A456UR is okay A456URK is newer hardware

Note: what resolution I change is on the game. So when I play the game, I'm using Nvidia GeForce 930M. Intel is only for displaying others than the game.
Please help me how to show high resolution display on monitor with lower resolution than display example: monitor 1366x768. But I want show 3200 x 1800 display on the game without cut off or only show half. But the display is more shrunken / smaller but FIT without downsampling.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

First, yes you can view an image with a much higher resolution than your monitor on your monitor, but it does that by shrinking, which is downsampling, basically.

But, the reason why it shrinks/downsamples is because the resolution of your monitor is a physical property of that monitor. Your monitor actually has 1366x768 little collects of colored pixel elements on it that comprise the image. If you wish to display anything that contains MORE information than that number of pixels on that monitor you WILL be shrinking/downsampling.

Further, if you could somehow force the graphics hardware to send an image at the source (game or image) resolution to that monitor there would be even further issues because that monitor is only designed to accept sufficient image information to fill each of its pixels and no more. If you were to somehow send data with more pixels worth of information to that screen there would be problems.

So no, you have requested the impossible.